# Couldn't connect to host (Error 7) in multi-threaded CURL

Tags: linux, multithreading, curl, connection, libcurl

I'm trying to run [this sample](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html) on an ARM-based training board. My OS configuration is OK & there is no problem in single-thread mode, but when I want to try it in multi-threaded manner, [curl_earsy_perform](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) always returns error 7 (CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT).
I re-checked whatever I thought may cause this error, but I couldn't resolve it. any idea?

Comment: Did you got your answer??I am also facing this problem on mipsel multicore architec.